# Reading Composite Document File V2 Document (.msg) files in ubuntu

Tags: text, encoding, msg

I have a large dump of data from an outlook email account that comes entirely in .msg files. A quick call to ubuntu's file method revealed that they were Composite Document File V2 Documents (whatever that means). I would really like to be able to read these files as plaintext. Is that possible at all?

Update: Turns out it wasn't totally possible to do what I wanted for large scale data mining on these kinds of files which was a bummer. In case you face the same issue I made a library to address this issue. https://github.com/Slater-Victoroff/msgReader

Documentation isn't great, but it's a pretty small library so it should be self explanatory.

Comment: btw it's not "ubuntu's" file "method", it's POSIX (or at least UNIX) command.

Comment: Basically the same question is answered in the [more appropriate] Super User community - http://superuser.com/questions/99250/opening-a-msg-file-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I faced the same problem this morning. I didn't find any information on the file format but it was possible to extract the required information from the file using strings and grep:

```
strings -e l *.msg | grep pattern
```

The -e l (that's a small L) converts from UTF-16.

This will only work if you can grep the data you need from the file (i.e. all required lines contain a standard string or pattern).

Comment: Ah, forgot to update. I just went ahead and built a library that parse out a text version of the email from the raw .msg file. Will link to it for all poor souls facing this problem. https://github.com/Slater-Victoroff/msgReader

Comment: Found documentation on the file format here: http://www.openoffice.org/sc/compdocfileformat.pdf ; I haven't read through it or tried to use it, but it may be useful.

Comment: @retracile Great find! I'll totally be looking into this.

Comment: This might get you more than you bargained for. If you e.g. export a list of email addresses that are in a group to a `.msg` file and then delete one of the addresses, `strings -e l` will still show the deleted address, as the particular stream in the .msg file for that deleted address is truncated, but the actual address containing words not overwritten.